# Getting a sinatra app to serve from a vm

Tags: ruby, macos, sinatra, vmware-fusion

I'm running vmware fusion 5 on osx 10.8, my guest OS is Arch Linux, currently I'm able to ssh into the guest os perfectly fine via `ssh 172.16.4.191` however when i try a simple sinatra app

```
require 'sinatra'

get '/hi' do
  "Hello world!!!!!!!"
end
```

`ruby hi.rb`

```
2013-04-06 19:45:18] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2013-04-06 19:45:18] INFO  ruby 2.0.0 (2013-02-24) [x86_64-linux]
== Sinatra/1.4.2 has taken the stage on 4567 for development with backup from WEBrick
[2013-04-06 19:45:18] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=426 port=4567
```

it is not available from my host OS

```
curl 172.16.4.191:4567
curl: (7) couldn't connect to host
```

Any suggestions would be great, and of course I will provide more information as needed.

Edit:

Share with my mac is selected, "The virtual machine shares the ip address of the Mac on the external network. The mac provides NAT for network traffic form the virtual machine"

Edit:

I've switched over to bridged mode, and it's now sitting on my lan, i can still ssh into it, still no such luck connecting to my sinatra app.

and the iptables shows no rules

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Comment: The answer most likely is to do with VMWare networking settings. If you have networking on the VM guest via NAT, you will need to edit the port-forwarding settings and add the new port. Could you add your VM's networking settings (as seen in the VMWare application that controls guest properties)?

Comment: I just have 'Internet sharing' share with my mac enabled, is there a more advanced section in fusion?

Comment: Yes, VMWare has a lot of networking options. Nowadays I use VirtualBox, so cannot refer you directly. But start the  VMWare Fusion app where you defined the guest machine, and look for networking options. There will be some general ones for the host, and specific ones for the guest. There are at least three different strategies that enable guest to network, and you could be using more than one as well . . .

Comment: And if course the guest os may be running a firewall

Comment: I updated it with the iptables of the guest, and have switched to bridged mode instead of the NAT.

Comment: All the VMWare networking modes make compromises on what you can do, in order to allow two OSs to share one physical network connection. I know NAT better than bridged mode. In NAT, there is a section on guest config where you can add port forwarding. Have you tried that option?

Comment: If VMWare is not a strict requirement for you, you should check out [Vagrant](http://www.vagrantup.com/). It's a bliss to work with under Ruby (wraps Oracle's VirtualBox)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need this line in your hi.rb:

```
set :bind, '0.0.0.0'
```

The [Document](http://www.sinatrarb.com/configuration.html#__server_hostname_or_ip_address) says '0.0.0.0' is the default value. It's wrong.

Comment: The default is localhost if the environment is 'development'. It is 0.0.0.0 otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone is trying to do this on mac / windows 7 with vmware with NAT/sinatra, make sure IIS manager is installed and configured with (connect to server -> localhost:4567).

from my windows browser , localhost:4567/promo_id/ works

from my browser in mac, http://172.16.178.xxx:4567/promo_id/  where 172.16.178.xxx is the IPv4 Address from ipconfig